# How to run an existing REACT project

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Beginner here, please help.
(1)If I have the files of a react project which was built on codesandbox or by another dev, how do I run the app and make changes in VSCode on my own machine.
(2)How do I run an existing personal create-react-app project on my machine, so as to continue buliding?

Comment: in the terminal run `npm install` and then `npm start` https://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial-react/setup/

Comment: Pretty much just [npm start](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUdOf63M_WA)

Comment: This might help: [run existing react app in vscode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUdOf63M_WA)

Answer (score 17):

Open a terminal on vscode, then make sure you already node installed.
Type `npm install` after that `npm run start` or whatever command to run, you can see on `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally closed VS Code or your local server tab, you can manually go to the folder, then right click and choose open in terminal, "open your project folder in terminal". Run `npm start`.
It will start development server with hot reloading at http://localhost:3000/

Answer (score -1):

The first thing you need is to install updated version of nodejs, you can type to google “download nodejs” and make sure you download the stable version.
You need to open a terminal, also make sure you can locate your file path then type:
cd your file path: your-appName (this should be the name of your app)